# Jquery UI (drag and drop)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I m creating an application using svg, for drag and drop i use Jquery UI. Is it possible to bind Jquery UI event inside another Jquery UI event.?

**//see over and drop events**

```
 $("#droppable").droppable({
 accept: ".draggable",
 activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
 hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
 drop: function() {

     $(this)
         .addClass("afterdrop")
         .find("p")
         .html("Dropped!").draggable('disable');

 },
 out: function() {
     console.log("out")
 },
 over: function() {
     drop: function() {
         //something here

     }
 }

 });
 });
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. But there might be other ways to achieve what you want. So, can you explain what are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: @TJ, I found another way to achieve that. Thanks for your info! :)